# Share Multiple images + Text in Whatsapp in Android

Tags: android, whatsapp

I want to share multiple images with a single text on Whatsapp.
I am using this code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text caption message!!");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT, "<html>Text caption message!!");
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.setType("image/jpeg");
    intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files);
    startActivity(intent);
```

This code is working fine **but the problem is that the text is coming on every image**. I want the text to be placed on only one image. Is there any way I can do that? TIA

Comment: Looks like the problem is in Whatsapp, not with your code. Or did you find anything to solve this?

Comment: Any solution to this problem ?